# Finding the limit of sequence

Tags: calculus

> Find the limit of
>   $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(
>     \sin \frac{n}{n^2+1^2} + 
>     \sin \frac{n}{n^2+2^2} + \dotsb +
>     \sin \frac{n}{n^2+n^2}
> \right)
> $$

I think it is a Riemann Integral but I didn't find the expression of Riemann Integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\gg 0$, $\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}\approx 0$ and hence $\frac{\sin\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}}{\frac n{n^2+k^2}}\approx 1$. This allows us to forget about the sine.
Then the summands become
$$ \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\frac1n\cdot\frac{n^2}{n^2+k^2}=\frac1n\frac{1}{1+(k/n)^2}=\frac{f(k/n)}n$$
with $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$, and there you have your Riemann sum

Comment: More specifically, since $\sin{x} = x + O(x^3)$ and $\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $k$, it follows that each term is within $O(\frac{1}{n^3})$ of $\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$, and hence the sum is within $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ of the corresponding sum.

Comment: I felt this is not a rigorous proof, since the number of summands is not fixed. You have to take account in the error when you approximate $\sin x$ by $x$.

Comment: @Solitary Yeah, but not really, because the summands are all positive: For $0<\epsilon<1$ we know that for $n>n_0(\epsilon)$ we have $0<(1-\epsilon)\frac{f(k/n)}n<\sin\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}<(1+\epsilon)\frac{f(k/n)}n$ and hence $(1-\epsilon)\frac1n\sum_k f(k/n)<\sum_k\sin\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}<(1+\epsilon)\frac1n\sum_k f(k/n)$.

Answer (score 4):

Use the inequality for $x \in (0, \pi/2)$:
$$x\cos x < \sin x < x.$$
The upper bound of the summation is 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{n}{n^2 + i^2}.\tag{1}$$
While since $\cos x$ is decreasing on $(0, \pi/2)$, a lower bound of the summation is 
$$\cos\left(\frac{n}{n^2 + 1}\right)\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{n}{n^2 + i^2}. \tag{2}$$
Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(n/(n^2 + 1)) = 1$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ have the same limit as $n \to \infty$. The squeeze principle then identifies the limit of the original sum is the same as the limit of $(1)$, which you can handle it with Riemann sum.

Comment: Nice job finding rigorous bounds.