# Calculus (Limits) Doubt: $\theta - \cfrac{\theta^3}{3!} < \sin \theta < \theta$ use to solve limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

Following is the question I've been trying to work on but can't get enough of it:

> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin\left(\cfrac{n}{n^2+1^2}\right) + \sin\left(\cfrac{n}{n^2+2^2}\right) + \cdots + \sin\left({\cfrac{n}{n^2+n^2}}\right) $$

I'm required to find the value of the above limit. All I could think about is to take $n^2$ common from numerator and denominator of each term.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin\left(\cfrac{1/n}{1+1^2/n^2}\right) + \sin\left(\cfrac{1/n}{1+2^2/n^2}\right) + \cdots + \sin\left({\cfrac{1/n}{1+n^2/n^2}}\right) $$

Now since $n \to \infty$ then shouldn't each term inside the sine function be zero and thus value of limit be zero? Where am I going wrong in this approach?

Also, I found a trick for this question specified in my book as:

To use the following inequality : $$\color{blue}{\theta - \cfrac{\theta^3}{3!} < \sin \theta < \theta }$$

And then to replace $\theta$ with $\cfrac{n}{n^2+k^2}$. I've never seen this inequality before, can anyone refer to the proof of this inequality? (or give the proof).

**EDIT**:

After working with the suggestions posted in the comments and answers: (and the link of the duplicate post)

I do get the following equation:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cfrac{1}{n} \left(\cfrac{1}{1+(k/n)^2}\right)$$

How can I convert this into Integral now?

Comment: Do you know about the Taylor expansion of the sine function?

Comment: Yeah $$\sin x =  x - x^3 / 3! + x^5/5! - .... $$

Comment: Okay yeah! I understand your hint. Well yeah, so, that's where it comes from. Thanks a lot for that. 

It is simply related to : $$\sin x = x - x^3/3! + \text{positive quantity} $$

$$\sin x > x - x^3/3!$$ Right?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali yep

Comment: Duplicated with [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511232/finding-the-limit-of-sequence/1511277#1511277). Please refer to the second answer therein.

Comment: Didn't know that there is already such a question posted. Thanks for referring to the post @Solitary

Comment: Please see the Edit, I'm stuck for how to interpret the term into integral now.

Comment: The limit if the sum is a Riemann sum and converges to $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to go through Riemann Sum and Integrals first. Thanks @Dr.MV

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure. - Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with saying that "each term goes to 0, so the sum goes to 0" is that while each individual term goes to 0, the *number* of terms goes to infinity, so you wind up with (approximately) a limit of $0 \times \infty$, meaning you have to do something more to get the limit to work.

As to the approximation, it comes from the Taylor series expansion of $\sin{\theta} = \theta - \frac{1}{3!} \theta^3 + \frac{1}{5!} \theta^5 - \dots$, where you can get the two inequalities by truncating the series and looking at the error term - although it will only be the case for *positive* $\theta$.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm a little confused now. Why was this inequality needed? How does it help us to forget sine function in the limit?

Comment: Because you can say that each of the sine functions is stuck between two values (based on the two inequalities). Then you just have to show that the two values have the same limit, and you can apply the squeeze theorem to say that the series with sines has the same limit.

Comment: Okay yes. Can you please see the Edit in the question and suggest any way to get the question into Integral?

Answer (score 3):

(Proof without Taylor series)

First we prove the right side.
$$\begin{align}
&f(x)=\sin x, \quad g(x)=x\\
&f(0)=g(0)\\
&f'(x)=\cos x \leq 1=g'(x)\\
&\therefore f(x)\leq g(x)
\end{align}$$

Now we prove the left side.
$$\begin{align}
&h(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!},\quad f(x)=\sin x\\
&h(0)=f(0)\\
&f'(x)-h'(x)=\cos x-\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\\
&f'(0)-h'(0)=0\\
&f''(x)-h''(x)=-\sin x+x\geq 0 \text{ (we proved it above)}\\
&\therefore h'(x)\leq f'(x)\quad\text{and}\quad h(x)\leq f(x)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Didn't know that it will come into use here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

As pointed out in comments, the Taylor Expansion for $\sin(x)$ is
$$\sin(\theta) = \theta - \frac{\theta^3}{3!} + O(\theta^5) > \theta - \frac{\theta^3}{3!}$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't consider it as a rigorous proof of the inequality. Somehow you need to deal with the $O(\theta^5)$ terms more explicitly. Since the inequality should hold for all $\theta$, not only for the small $\theta$.